# Tipo de campo en migration para guardar numero de horas

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js

Quisiera pedir recomendación para guardar el numero de horas en la base de datos.

Como se muestra en la imagen, necesito guardar en un campo, el numero de horas ej: 1:30 (una hora y media):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo había puesto un unsignedDecimal, para guardar 1.30, pero no se si estará correcto, para después compararlo con el tiempo real que ingresaré en otro campo y poder comparar lo en la misma unidad de horas.
(Estoy trabajando con laravel 5.7 y vue.js)
Espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Al ser basada en opiniones puede terminar cerrada, sin embargo yo creo debes usar el tipo de dato `time` de este modo: `$table->time('sunrise');`

Comment: tu idea no es mala, pero si después necesitas hacer cálculos mejor usar el tipo de dato **time**, después te vas a ahorrar hartos problemas

Comment: @Aprendiz  y Sebastián Miranda
 Si con time está perfecto.
eso si, me está guardando con los segundos (02:30:00). Me imagino que con Carbon, u alguna otra función tendré que darle formato para la vista.
¿O existe en mysql alguna personalización para este campo?

Es mas que nada para no tener problemas luego en los calculos.
Gracias

Comment: en MySQL se haría así: `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(tiempo, "%H:%i") as tiempo` para formatear el registro, solo sería revisar con Carbon como hacerlo